# Why is MSCORLIB messing type verification in PowerShell classes?

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-assembly, mscorlib

I have stumbled upon very strange behavior in PowerShell.
I, by default, load MSCORLIB assembly in every PowerShell script which I write (I know that it is loaded by default, but ok) and I did not have any problems until now. It appears that if I load MSCORLIB in a class and then use object of that class within another class, PowerShell claims that this object is not instance of itself, but when I do not load MSCORLIB assembly, everything works as expected.
To better understand me, we will need 3 files whose code follows:

CLASS.PS1:

```
USING ASSEMBLY MSCORLIB;
CLASS CLASS{}
```

CLASS2.PS1:

```
. .\CLASS.PS1;
CLASS CLASS2
{
    STATIC METHOD([CLASS]$PARAMETER){}
}
```

SCRIPT.PS1

```
. .\CLASS.PS1;
. .\CLASS2.PS1;
[CLASS2]::METHOD([CLASS]::NEW());
PAUSE
```

So, `CLASS` file defines a `CLASS`. `CLASS2` file loads `CLASS` and defines another class, `CLASS2`. It has a `METHOD` which accepts one `PARAMETER` and validates that it is of type `CLASS`.
I use test `SCRIPT` which loads both classes and then calls `METHOD` from `CLASS2` and gives it new instance of `CLASS`.

Since `PARAMETER` of `METHOD` is indeed of type `CLASS`, and `METHOD` validates its `PARAMETER` to be of type `CLASS`, validation should pass and this code should not do anything (since `METHOD` is empty).
However, this code produces following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "PARAMETER", with value: "CLASS", for "METHOD" to type "CLASS": "Cannot convert the "CLASS" value of type "CLASS" to
type "CLASS"."
At C:\PLAYT\SOURCES\3.4\SYSTEM\SCRIPT.PS1:3 char:1
+ [CLASS2]::METHOD([CLASS]::NEW());
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

As you can see, PowerShell is trying to convert `CLASS` to itself for no reason. This is totally unlogical and I can not find any bugs in this code.

But what is most surprising is that if I remove `USING ASSEMBLY MSCORLIB;` from `CLASS` file, everything works as expected and validation passes.

I do not see the reason why not loading `MSCORLIB` assembly at the beginning of `CLASS` file makes a difference. It should be none, since `MSCORLIB` assembly is loaded by default by PowerShell itself much before PowerShell even opens a script. So, `MSCORLIB` gets loaded no matter if I explicitly load it in `CLASS` or not.
One more thing. Loading `MSCORLIB` assembly in `CLASS2` or in `SCRIPT` does not generate error. Error is only generated if `MSCORLIB` is loaded in `CLASS`.

Informations that might be relevant for problem reproduction:
PowerShell version: 5.1.14393.2312
.net version: 4.0.30319.42000
Windows version: 10.0.14393.2312
OS: Windows Server 2016

So, why is this happening? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I have no explanation, but I'm asking pragmatically: why do you use `USING ASSEMBLY MSCORLIB`, even though it's not necessary? Note that the statement will break right away in PowerShell _Core_. Also, out of curiosity, why is your code in all-uppercase?

Comment: No some important reason, but I like to explicitely write all things which are implicite. For example, I load MSCORLIB whenever I use .net in my code (which is allways), I write RETURN; at end of every VOID function or method, in every class I include empty static and dynamic constructors even if i do not use them and so on. Not required since it is implicitely included, but I simply like things to be explicitely defined. It is simpler and more understandsble for me on that way. Yea, good thing I do not use core.

Comment: Because I usually write everything everywhere with caps lock on. All my programs are written with caps lock key on (unless in case sensitive programming languages where I must use lowercase letters or else syntax will not be correct). I also write with caps lock on on all websites, my mails, my chat messages, just everything.
I used to write posts on stack overflow with caps lock on, but stack overflow kept deleting my accounts. Eventually I have got tired of creating new accounts on stack overflow each time when i needed to ask a question, so I agreed to press caps lock while I write posts..

Comment: ...on stack overflow. I never had time to gain any reputation before account got deleted. But this is only exception and only place where I use lovercase letters. Everywhere else are uppercase. Just because uppercase letters look better to me and it is more simple not having to press caps lock for each time when I need to switch from lower to upper case letters.

Comment: The message is actually telling you there are now two types named `CLASS`, in two different assemblies (hence the conversion error). The exact cause is vague, but keep in mind that dot-sourcing does not simply reference a file for import -- it actually runs the code, meaning that running `script.ps1` runs `class.ps1` twice -- once at the beginning of the script and once when `class2.ps1` is run. Evidently the `using assembly` is throwing something off that prevents the class definition from being linked up to the previously generated assembly (and this is not restricted to `mscorlib`).